# Issue using aws sagemaker InvokeEndpoint inside of Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-sagemaker

I am working on an experiment with integrating ML predictions inside my RDS Postgres 14.6.7 database. I followup this tutorial and managed to get the data loaded, sagemaker model created, sagemaker training completed and endpoint deployed. Everything was looking good.

Then I wrote some code to test the endpoint prediction.

```
import boto3
import json

# Create a Boto3 client for SageMaker
client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')

# Set the name of the SageMaker endpoint to invoke
endpoint_name = 'Custom-sklearn-model-2024-03-26-20-15-12'

# Set the content type of the input data
content_type = 'application/json'

# Hardcoded input data
input_data = [
    [1454.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 34.0, 0.7, 83.0, 4.0, 3.0, 250.0, 1033.0, 3419.0, 7.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], 
    [1092.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 10.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.5, 167.0, 3.0, 14.0, 468.0, 571.0, 737.0, 14.0, 4.0, 11.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
]

# Convert the input data to JSON format
payload = json.dumps(input_data)

# Invoke the SageMaker endpoint
response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    ContentType=content_type,
    Body=payload
)

# Get the response from the SageMaker endpoint
result = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

print(result)
```

This code had an output to

`[3, 0]`

Everything is looking good. I go to my RDS cluster to verify I have an IAM Role for sagemaker. This role is there and Active for sagemaker.

[image: RDS Cluster IAM Roles]

Now I will run a simulate using that role to InvokeEndpoint on my SageMaker Endpoint. I selected the role and selected sagemaker and set the endpoint to the arn of the specific endpoint. Everything passes.

[image]

So now my database should be able to invoke it. In PGAdmin, I install the aws_ml extension and now have access to the aws_sagemaker.invoke_endpoint function.

When I run this query, I expect the results to be returned instead it times out.

```
SELECT aws_sagemaker.invoke_endpoint (
    'Custom-sklearn-model-2024-03-26-20-15-12',
    1,
    1454.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 34.0, 0.7, 83.0, 4.0, 3.0, 250.0, 1033.0, 3419.0, 7.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0
);
```

and this is the error I get

'ERROR:  invoke_endpoint failed with error message: "curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached"'

I checked cloudwatch logs for the endpoint and it's never reaching that. I can't figure out what is wrong with it. It seems like the database isn't using the role for sagemaker. In some tutorials with mysql, there seems to be a parameter "aws_default_sagemaker_role" in the the cluster parameter group. Unfortunately, that parameter isn't available to me and not sure if I am missing something to configure the default sagemaker role or not.